# How to create use CASE statement inside WHERE using parameters in HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

guys thans for  time and help

i have HQL Query using case and paramater and i get a error when i set the parameters

my query is:

```
SELECT 
IC.Sources, 
IC.Total, 
IC.Destination, 
IC.Where, 
ICP.Date, 
ICP.filedirectory, 
ICP.filename 
FROM IcmA AS IC, IcmProc AS ICP
WHERE IC.uniqueid = ICP.uniqueid
AND IC.Sources = :Num OR IC.Destination= :Num
AND CASE 
WHEN LENGTH(IC.Sources) = 1 OR LENGTH(IC.Destination) = 1 THEN
:NBalance
WHEN LENGTH(IC.Sources) > 1 OR LENGTH(IC.Destination) > 1 THEN
:NBalance
ELSE
:NBalance
END = :NBalance
AND(DATE_FORMAT(ICP.Date, '%Y/%m/%d') >= :fDate AND DATE_FORMAT(ICP.Date, '%Y/%m/%d') <= :tDate) ORDER BY ICP.Date DESC
```

Error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.ParameterNode cannot be cast to org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.SelectExpression>
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.ParameterNode cannot be cast to org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.SelectExpression
```

Comment: how you execute the request ? did you correctly set all parameters : Num, NBalance, fDate, tDate

Comment: yes all parameter are set as string

Comment: can you please post your code ?

Comment: i am using this query on WaveMaker

Comment: i test the query on netbeans and i get the same error

Comment: netbeans error java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.ParameterNode cannot be cast to org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.SelectExpression

Comment: hi, sobody? hi, sobody?0